# Which variance test is needed?

Tags: variance, levenes-test

I have the following data

A= c(45, 55, 46, 67, 23)
B= c(34, 54, 29, 66, 58)
C= c(56, 76, 60, 37, 55)

I want to know if there is a significant difference between the variance of A, B and C, which test should I perform? Levene test?

Comment: Please say more about your problem. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @Dave, The values of A, B and C are the five values of 5 fold CV. I have identified the algorithm (i.e. C) which have low variance, it means algorithm C is more stable (low variance) algorithm. But I also wanted to know if there is a statistical difference (p value less than 0.05) in the variance (i.e. five values of A, B, and C) of the three algorithms.

Comment: Having data from the folds of a cross validation changes the problem quite a bit, as you definitely lack the independence assumption. Do `45`, `34` and `56` all come from the same data split but with three different models?

Comment: Yes it does.. From same split but with three different models